# python creating convolve function for arrays

Tags: python, math, python-2.7

I have two arrays,

```
a = [3, 6, 8, 2, 5, 5]
b = [2, 7, 9]
```

and I need to create a new array `c` which takes the values and adds them like this: `a[0+0]*b[0] + a[0+1]*b[1] + a[0+2]*b[2] = (3*2) + (6*7) + (9*8) = 6 + 42 + 72` which means `c[0] = 120`

I'm completely lost on how to do this anything to point me in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: Is c[1] then supposed to be `a[1]*b[0] + a[2]*b[1] + a[3]*b[2]` and so on? Are the lengths of `a` and `b` fixed (or at least, is `a` always longer than `b`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `c[k] = a[k+0]*b[0] + a[k+1]*b[1] + a[k+2]*b[2]`

then

```
>>> c = [sum(i*j for i,j in zip(a[k:], b)) for k in range(4)]
>>> c
[120, 86, 75, 84]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
total = 0
for n in range(0, min(len(a), len(b))):
    total += a[n] * b[n]
```

[range function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

Comment: don't you mean `range(min(len(a), len(b)))` there?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want. It borrows some of the code from @DukeSilver's answer and makes it build a list, rather than just calculating a single value. My assumption is that `a` is always longer than `b`.

```
c = [sum(a[i+j]*b[j] for j in range(len(b))) for i in range(len(a) - len(b) + 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.convolve` or do you want to write your own function?